# How to have a form running when called from an ActionMenu in a Palette?

Tags: interface, palettes

I create a FormFunction "form":

```
Clear[form];
form = FormFunction[
   "Information" ->
    RepeatingElement[
     CompoundElement[
      <|
       {"Property", Style["Property", 16, Black, Bold]} -> "String",
       {"Unit", Style["Unit", 16, Black, Bold]} -> "String"
       |>
      ]
     ],
   AppearanceRules ->
    <|
     "Title" -> " ",
     "Description" -> 
      Column[{Style["Enter your information", Bold, 20, Red]}]
     |>
   ];
```

1 (of 2). The following evaluates the FormFunction directly in the notebook (which is what I want)

```
form[]
```

2 (of 2). But the next code do not return in the notebook the FormFunction evaluated as I want, it returns instead a unevaluated FormFunction[___], which is not the same as 1.

```
CreatePalette[
  Grid[
   {
    {Style["Data", FontSize -> 14, FontWeight -> Bold],
    ActionMenu[
      "Create",
      {
       "Create an element" :>
        NotebookApply[
         SelectedNotebook[],
         Cell[
          BoxData[
          ToBoxes[form]
           ],
          "Output"]
         ]
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    ]
   ];
```

Comment: how is this question different from [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/261660/58370)?

Comment: We solved the problem for Plot and Graphics of the question you refer to but did NOT for "form".

Comment: We are several trying to solve this problem and we have decided to isolate the "form" problem from the rest of the code of the other question (Plot and Graphics in particular) in order to simplify it to the maximum, better understand it and... make that piece of code running.